# XSL Transformation, emoji and attributes

Tags: xslt, emoji, surrogate-pairs

I'm encountering issue with emojis when trying to generate html output using xsl transformation under certain circumstances.

For instance, I've tested following xsl with different transformation engines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;!doctype html&gt;</xsl:text>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
      </head>
      <body>
        <textarea></textarea><br/>
        <input type="text" value=""/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I tested with exact same code (based on JAXP definition) for all transformers. I only changed the transformer instance class reference.

Saxon gives correct result:

[image]

Java internal repackaged transformer based on xalan (aka com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl) is correct when emoji is put as text in textarea body, but generates wrong result for `<input>` field: it seems that emoji is wrong encoded when put in `value` attribute:

[image]

Xalan 2.7.2 gives even worse result:

[image]

For different reasons (mainly license one), I would prefer using Xalan transformer. Any idea how I can make xalan manage emoji correctly ?

EDIT

The transformation is performed with following code:

```
TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance(
        "com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl",
        null);
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xsl));
DocumentSource domSource = new DocumentSource(doc);
OutputStream stream = response.getOutputStream();

transformer.transform(domSource, new StreamResult(stream));

stream.flush();
stream.close();
```

where `doc` is a dom4j document, `xsl` is the inputstream containing above stylesheet and `response` is a HttpServletResponse object which will receive the transformation result.

Comment: If you have `<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8"/>` in your stylesheet, why do you also hard code  `<meta charset="UTF-8"/>` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in the HTML the stylesheet creates? With the proper use of the Transformer it should create the right `meta` when serializing to HTML, based on the `xsl:output` directive. And how does your Java JAXP code look exactly, does it use a StreamResult to create an HTML file?

Comment: Hi, I added the code of JAXP transformation. I agree `meta` declaration is messed up, but the issue is not linked to this declaration imho since behaviour is obviously dependant on transformer, not on stylesheet nor browser.

Comment: As you are sending results directly to a browser, I suppose, with that servlet response, what does the network console show as the content type and perhaps charset for the response in the case of the messed up Xalan rendering?

Comment: I tried removing the `<meta>` from xsl + add both doctype-system versions in xsl:output, but it does not change anything. Wireshark shows be that transformation returns `<textarea>&#128077;&#127995;</textarea><br><input type="text" value="&#55357;&#55356;">`

Comment: It might be the known issue https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419 though I can't tell for sure and I am not sure why my test with Xalan 2.7.1 at xsltransform.net seemed to work out.

Comment: I guess the xsltransform.net test might have worked out as there the result is not serialized to a stream and encoded as UTF-8 but rather passed around as an UTF-16 encoded string.

Comment: Xalan 2.7.1 gives me same wrong result than 2.7.2. But Xalan 2.6.0 gives me correct result ! I already experienced some troubles with xalan 2.7.* on encoding. It was for iso-8859-1 encoding and after bunch of research in xalan source, I discovered that xsl:output encoding had to be declared "iso8859-1" instead of "iso-8859-1". Not sure this is same issue here since I'm using utf-8, but I'll dive in xalan source again to find how attributes are handled. Thanks a lot for your help. I'll tell if I can find something.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <textarea></textarea><br/>
        <input type="text" value=""/>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

with Xalan 2.7.1 at http://xsltransform.net/ and both thumbs seems to be shown fine i.e. the serialized HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<input value="" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

which renders as

[image]

Comment: I think the doctype system identifier should more properly be `about:legacy-compat`. https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#the-doctype

Comment: @ConalTuohy, thanks, now tested and fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I finally decided to fork xalan-java project and patch the serializer by myself. After compilation of the patch, I'm able to have correct emojis for both attributes and text with utf-8 xsl output.

The patch commit is following https://github.com/morbac/xalan-java/commit/a685171e1b621e9b63c8507f467a395fd1fc96a4. It fixes the issue for both input and textarea. The jar with fixed classes is [available here](https://github.com/morbac/xalan-java/releases/tag/2.7.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

After a day of research, I have come to the conclusion that this is a bug in [xalan html serializer (line 1440 and following)](https://github.com/apache/xalan-j/blob/trunk/src/org/apache/xml/serializer/ToHTMLStream.java#L1440) with surrogate characters (char between \ud800 and \udbff). As mentioned in comments, xalan 2.6.0 makes a correct transformation, but xalan 2.7.* does not.

[Martin Honnen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/252228/martin-honnen) mentioned the [XALANJ-2419](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2419). I also found other tickets related to this issue ([XALANJ-2617](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/XALANJ-2617), https://github.com/apache/xalan-j/pull/4, etc.) I tried to implement some fixes. For instance [the version suggested here](https://github.com/apache/xalan-j/pull/4#issuecomment-431864049)  effectively fixes the issue for my `<input>` field but it remains the issue with textarea.

[image]

I'll try to fork xalan and fix the issue for both attribute and text. Meanwhile, the easiest way to work around the issue is to change the replace the "UTF-8" encoding with "UTF-16" in `xsl:output`. This fixes both issues.

[image]